# How to completely stop and unload external loaded SWF sounds in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, external, loader

I have created a flash player that loads external swfs and control them through stop, play, frwd buttons. the external swf is added on next previous buttons click using loader class.

to remove the preiously added SWF and add new one I use the following code

```
l.unloadAndStop();

l.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loadProgress);

l.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadHandler);

l.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loadError);

var Request:URLRequest =  new URLRequest(xmlData.Page[Current_Page_No].URL[0]);

l = new Loader();

l.load(Request);

l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,     loadProgress,false,0,true);

l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadHandler,false,0,true);

l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loadError);
```

every thing works fine as loading complete before I click the next button, I face an issue when I click next quickly before loading the previous content completed.
the loader seems to continue loading the previous content and add its sound to stage, the sounds don't seem to stop even though its not within the current SWF. I can't simply stop all sounds because I'll have other SWFs with sound. and nothing seems to work with sound stream even unloadAndStop please help.

Comment: Have you considered disabling the buttons while loading/unloading processes?

Comment: No, I didn't try disabling button, but I intend this for elearing purposes and I think this might annoy the students.

Comment: I would do some button disabling as well while loading like Sam said.

Comment: What happens if you execute l.close(); before anything else? Also, why aren't you using weak referencing for the IO error handling in addition to ProgressEvent.PROGRESS and Event.COMPLETE? Weakly referencing the loader object 2 times out of 3 won't actually help. :)

Comment: I tried using weak reference but it didn't help, I also added l.close() but I got the following error:
Error #2029: This URLStream object does not have a stream opened.
 at flash.display::Loader/close()
 at Lo_flash2_fla::MainTimeline/Add_Content()
 at Lo_flash2_fla::MainTimeline/Start_Display()
 at Lo_flash2_fla::MainTimeline/Complete_Handler()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
 at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

Comment: Weak listener references won't help with the problem you're having but they will help in other ways.  The only reason I mention them is that you specify weak referencing for 2 of your event handlers but not for the 3rd.  Unless I misunderstand what you're trying to do, it's really better for all of the event listeners in question to be weak references.  You don't want those contentLoaderInfo objects lying around after you're done with them.

Comment: For the URLStream error, you could either test first to see if a load is in progress, or just wrap it in a try block.  That should at least let you figure out if l.close() gets you the behavior you want.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I used weak reference in all listeners to improve memory management. I have also tries close but it didn't seem to help the sound is still playing in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is Fixed for now

here is what I used to remove the old externally loaded SWF

```
//stop all sounds
SoundMixer.stopAll();

System.gc();//force Grabage collection (might not work)

while (Container.numChildren > 0){ Container.removeChildAt(0); }//remove from stage

try
{

currentSWF.stop();//Stop the Loaded Movie clip copy

while (currentSWF.numChildren > 0){ currentSWF.removeChildAt(0); }//remove all children

currentSWF = null;//null its reference

}

catch(er:*)
{
trace("MC null");
}

l.unloadAndStop(true);//unload the loader

l.unload();

// remove event listeners
l.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loadProgress);

l.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadHandler);

l.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loadError);
```

but mostly what helped was **SoundMixer.stopAll()** and having a **stop** at the end of the

**externally** loaded SWF with Audio. Hope this works for others

Answer (score 0):

To stop all sounds you can try `SoundMixer.stopAll();` before you call your `load()`, and maybe even before `l.unloadAndStop()`. I've never used it for loaded swfs but it's worth a try.